# JavaFx : setting a Boolean inside a button and taking it out

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a password login screen but can't seem to take the Boolean out of the button I use to check if the user has entered the password.

```
    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        boolean loggedIn = loggedInchecker.check(user, pass, 
    correctPassword, correctUsername);  
    });
```

Is there any way to take the Boolean out of the button.
(I'm still very new to coding.)

Comment: yes just declare this boolean variable as a class variable

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to do with the boolean. Usually I'd expect a login button to do something like this: `if (login(authentification)) { openMainWindow(); } else { showLoginError(); }` (at least simple programs where no "session" is used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to give us more clarification do you no longer need the variable if so just do this

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    loggedInchecker.check(user, pass, correctPassword, correctUsername);  
});
```

But if you need the variable still put `private boolean loggedIn` at the top where you are declaring your variables and in your program do this

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
   loggedIn = loggedInchecker.check(user, pass, correctPassword, correctUsername);  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!